# expressjs sending err_empty_response

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with my expressJS framework when I am sending a response with delay 200 seconds it's sending err_empty_response with status code 324

here is fakeTimer example

```
    fakeTimeout(req, res) {
    setTimeout(() => { res.json({success: true})}, 200000)
}
```

Comment: That's a long time for a response. Maybe there are some performance points to consider on your backend?

Comment: not I'm testing it in localhost

Answer (score 1):

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is a Google Chrome error code.

Actually, Chrome will automatically timeout requests when they exceeds 300 seconds, and there is no way to change that settings unfortunately.

One workaround could be to change the Keep Alive headers.

However, if one task is taking longer than one minute, you should really just don't let the user wait that amount of time and have a feedback later on the UI when it's completed.

Comment: I guess wget has a timeout as well which is reached because of your very long setTimeout.